# wrong resolution/refresh rate output after upgade to 13.10

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, xorg, resolution, display

I have a custom xorg.conf (need it because my lcd doesn't report it's correct capabilities) that worked fine in 13.04 but since upgading to 13.10 the lcd is incapable of displaying the output from x. Here's my conf file and my xorg log: http://pastebin.com/ruP3rCn3    What has changed in the upgrade that makes x output a different signal to my lcd with the same conf file as before?

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I run nvidia-settings I can specify resolution manually, hit "apply" and it changes to the right settings -- but after I save changes to xorg.conf, when I log out or reboot it goes back to 1024x768.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with Ubuntu 13.10 and Ubuntu Gnome 13.10.
Nvidia drivers 319 and 331 series - both same issue.